# Droid RAZR - Is there any way to clear the numbers from the screen when using the dialer?

Tags: phone-app, motorola-droid-razr

When I need to check my voicemail, I have to enter my password, of course.  However, when I do, it displays it in big, clearly visible characters across the top of the screen for the duration of the call.  I think this is incredibly stupid.  Is there any way to clear it after entering it?

EDIT:
I do realize there is the option to hide the dialpad and input box during the call.  However, whenever I need to use the dialpad again I need to make it visible, which then shows my password still at the top.

Comment: What android version is this?

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: I do realize there is the option to hide the dialpad and input
>   box during the call. However, whenever I need to use the dialpad again
>   I need to make it visible, which then shows my password still at the
>   top.

That is an indication of proximity sensor, when the handset is near the ear, the screen blanks out, when you're pulling the handset away, the screen comes back on and can see the dialpad, along with the numbers entered!

> Is there any way to clear it after entering it?

When you make a check to voicemail, you're dialing the number, then enter the password, then after checking the voicemail, you hangup, does that not clear the dialer?

In certain dialers, you can actually long press on the dialpad's top screen to bring up a menu, to select all, then cut... **OR** long press on the keypad's <kbd>backspace</kbd> button

Maybe, if this does not suffice, then the only thing that comes to mind, is to either shield the screen from prying eyes or, use an alternative dialer.

Comment: The proximity sensor feature is not what I was talking about.  That turns off the screen.  There is actually a button on the screen to hide the dialpad itself.  This is probably going to be my best bet.  As far as it clearing after ending the call, that's not the issue.  I don't want it visible while the call is active.  I did try long-pressing on the input box but it didn't do anything.  Also there is no keypad, so 'backspace' isn't an option.  I guess there isn't a way.  Perhaps an alternative dialer would work.  I hadn't thought of that.  Thanks.

Comment: OP: Please state what version of Android as I was taking a gamble with the question and not certain...

Comment: I believe it's 2.3.4 (yes I know it's old)

Comment: @vertigoelectric How did you avoid getting the ICS and JB updates?!

Comment: My phone is rooted, and I've blocked updates.